# How to write if condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i need to check `@SupplierCategory` and `@SupplierCode` is not equal to null by using if condition in sql server 2008

e.g

```
if (@SupplierCategory != null && @SupplierCode != null )
    begin
    end
else
    begin
    end
```

how to do it...thanks

Comment: flagged to close as a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (@SupplierCategory is not null AND @SupplierCode is not null )
    begin
    end
else
    begin
    end
```